# Get elements using children length in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to get `<td>` whose children length(size()) is 2 using Jquery. I am trying this but this returns me only size() & not the `<td>'s`.

```
grid.find("tr").find("td").children().size();
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)
The [`.size()`](http://api.jquery.com/size/) returns the number of elements in the jQuery object.

```
var tds = grid.find("tr").find("td").filter(function(){
   return $(this).children().length == 2;
});
//tds Contains only those tds with two children
```

Will return the `td`'s having 2 children.